# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on my ant junit task even when I have setted maxmemory="1024m"

Tags: memory, junit, ant, heap-memory

I am having an issue with my junit task. When I run it from eclipse, it goes well with the -Xmx1000m argument. It was working too in my ant task to but suddenly it stop working, throwing this out of memory exception. I have configured the maxmemory="1024m" on the ant task but with no success.

Here's the stack trace:

```
 [junit] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    [junit]     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    [junit]     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    [junit]     at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:420)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeInVM(JUnitTask.java:1339)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:831)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1785)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:785)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [junit]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    [junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    [junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    [junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    [junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
    [junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
    [junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'streamingCotizacionesDAO' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-core-Dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateTemplateSeguro' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplateSeguro'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplateSeguro' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dataAccess.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactorySeguro' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactorySeguro' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dataAccess.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    [junit]     ... 39 more
    [junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplateSeguro' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dataAccess.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactorySeguro' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactorySeguro' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dataAccess.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    [junit]     ... 55 more
    [junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactorySeguro' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dataAccess.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    [junit]     ... 65 more
    [junit] Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    [junit]     at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    [junit]     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    [junit]     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    [junit]     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.sql.Select.toStatementString(Select.java:68)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.loader.collection.BasicCollectionJoinWalker.initStatementString(BasicCollectionJoinWalker.java:128)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.loader.collection.BasicCollectionJoinWalker.<init>(BasicCollectionJoinWalker.java:62)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.loader.collection.BasicCollectionLoader.<init>(BasicCollectionLoader.java:53)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.loader.collection.BasicCollectionLoader.<init>(BasicCollectionLoader.java:40)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.loader.collection.BasicCollectionLoader.<init>(BasicCollectionLoader.java:31)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.loader.collection.BatchingCollectionInitializer.createBatchingCollectionInitializer(BatchingCollectionInitializer.java:92)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister.createCollectionInitializer(BasicCollectionPersister.java:297)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:541)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:294)
    [junit]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$5.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1467)
    [junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1465)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
```

Comment: I reckon you might have some kind of cyclic dependency in your autowiring configuration and that causes the out of memory. I know spring detects cyclic dependencies, but you might be triggering a bug in spring or doing something that doesn't actually work.

Comment: Hello Augusto! Thanks for your response! I thought about it can be something like that, but why is it only when running ant ? Shouldnt it break when I run it from the Eclipse plugin to?

Comment: Not really, there are some differences, specially around the classpath. If you can attach a profiler to ant, you'll be able to get a better picture as you'll probably see where is the infinite loop (from the stack trace it could be in Spring, Hibernate ... or maybe somewhere else :S). As a side note (not related to this question), if you are trying to run unit tests why do you start Spring?

Comment: That's great! do you know any one to recommend? Sorry for my ignorance. On the other side, We run our test not as a unit test but as integration test, the only thigs we mock are those ones that we do not have control as a web service or some thing like that.... Thaks again!

Comment: You can try [yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/). In my opinion, it's the best profiler for java... it's not cheap, but it ends up being very cheap. Otherwise you might be able to use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) as it has some CPU and memory profiling (and it's for free)

Comment: Thakns! I will try this!